# how to record then play audio without save to file android

Tags: file-descriptor, android-mediarecorder

I'm developing an app like `Talking Tom`

I tried to record audio, save to file then play with `Mediaplayer` in android but there is a bit delay to save the file then play. It is not smooth like `Talking Tom`

I saw that both `MediaRecorder` & `MediaPlayer` accept argument `FileDescriptor` in `setOutputFile` & `setDataSource`.

Is there any way to record then play without save to file ?

Do `SoundPool` & `Mediaplayer` can sound with byte array like `byte [] buffer` ?

Please help!

Comment: It seems must exist the way to do this without read-write to file system. because `Talking Tom` looks so smooth including `human voice recognition`

Answer (score 1):

AudioRecord has the ability to record to a buffer, which can be played without saving to a file. MediaRecorder, which can also record videos, cannot.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

Two previous related questions answered on stackoverflow:

[AudioRecord - how to get data in to buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492653/audiorecord-how-to-get-data-in-to-buffer)

[Android AudioRecord to File then use AudioTrack for Playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130374/android-audiorecord-to-file-then-use-audiotrack-for-playback)

I don't know if soundpool can be used with an array. The samples I seen and follow create multiple soundpools:

```
soundPool1 = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0); 
sound1 = soundPool1.load(getApplication(), R.raw.basskickdrum,1);
soundPoolA = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
soundA = soundPoolA.load(getApplication(),R.raw.closedhighhat,1);
soundPool2 = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
sound2 = soundPool2.load(getApplication(),R.raw.snare2,1);
```