# How to set MediaRecorder setOutputFile to null?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am trying to create an audio recorder app that records audio and should save audio only when users click on the save button. But the problem I am facing is that as soon as recording stops it saves automatically. And if I try to set setOutputFile to null then the app crashes.

**Code**

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
```

Does Anybody know how to save that audio recording manually?

Comment: You can try AudioRecord  ,more detail in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/34735609/5553085