# FloatControl.setValue showing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, audio

I am trying to receive sound from an android app. So far i'm able to send DatagramPacket from the android app. But when i try to receive that DatagramPacket in my JAVA server in my localhost java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is shown.

```
public class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 8888;
static int sampleRate = 44100;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("entering");
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8888);

    /**
     * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2 Byte size 9728 will
     * produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken. Byte size 1400
     * will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken. Byte size
     * 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken
     * then 9728.
     */

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[4000];

    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

    while (status == true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);

        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                receivePacket.getData());

        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());

        toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());


    }
}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {
        System.out.println("I am in to speaker");
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem
                .getLine(dataLineInfo);

        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine
                .getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volumeControl.setValue(100.0f);

        sourceDataLine.start();
        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        sourceDataLine.start();

        System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

        sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When i try to send the audio to the server the Java class `server` throws this exception. This is produced by `volumeControl.setValue(100.0f);`. Because when i set `volumeControl.setValue(6.0);`, this all works perfectly fine. What is causing this error and is there any way to fix it?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested value 100.0 exceeds allowable maximum value 6.0206.
at javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl.setValue(FloatControl.java:218)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL$Gain.setValue(DirectAudioDevice.java:853)
at com.company.Server.toSpeaker(Server.java:72)
at com.company.Server.main(Server.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Obviously the maximum value is 6.0206. Why do you want to set the value to 100.0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955958/android-audiorecord-to-server-over-udp-playback-issues here they set the value 100.0f and it works. So i think this can be set.

Comment: That would depend on the maximum that was set when the `FloatControl` was created. You can query the maximum by first getting the `MASTER_GAIN` `FloatControl` with `line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN)` and then call `getMaximum()` on the returned object. I can't say that I understand why you'd even want to try applying 100dB of gain on a stream.

Answer (score 0):

The range of a `FloatControl` may vary depending on the `SourceDataLine` so you must use the `FloatControl.getMinimum()` and `FloatControl.getMaximum()` methods to find out the range you are allowed to set.

You can also call `FloatControl.getUnits()` to get a string telling you the units of the control (usually dB).

`FloatControl.getPrecision()` gives you the precision of the control.

As an example on my Mac speakers the Master Gain range is -80.0 - 6.0206 dB.