# What mean this error? Invalid indirect reference 0x61382e48 in decodeIndirectRef

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I got this error in runtime (c++ jni)

```
W/dalvikvm(24772): Invalid indirect reference 0x61382e48 in decodeIndirectRef
E/dalvikvm(24772): VM aborting
F/libc    (24772): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 24975 (ldAndroidCaptur)
```

0x61382348 is a address that was passed from c++ to Java.

I don't know what mean is this message **Invalid indirect reference 0x........ in decodeIndirectRef**

Who can let me know it?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably post the code that causes this error.

Comment: @Michael, Here is a code in my old question about this problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471691/qt-jni-invalid-indirect-reference-0x61382e48-in-decodeindirectref

Comment: It means a method was expecting a Java-language object, but received a C++-language pointer instead. See e.g. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#local_and_global_references

Comment: @fadden, As you can see [my old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471691/qt-jni-invalid-indirect-reference-0x61382e48-in-decodeindirectref), I passed jbyte array into a call.

`int result = mAudioRecorder->callMethod<jint>("read", "([BII)I", buffers, offset, size);`

In Android, AudioRecorder's read function received byte[] array parameters.

In you think, what's my wrong in this call?