# Audio record in android and FFT

Tags: android, audio, fft, record, frequency

I am using this code I found to record mic audio, I am not writing the data into the PCM  file, I simply write the data to a ByteArrayOutputStream variable: [Android AudioRecord example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499042/android-audiorecord-example)

When I finish the record, I have a byte array. How should I analyze the byte array using FFT? Simply speaking, I am trying to analyze a FSK sound wave.

Comment: What's your problem? There are many fast FFT implementations for android. Just use a library.

Comment: @codemonkey I'll clarify the question,I found this implementation: http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/html/FFT_8java-source.html I dont really know how to use it, and there are 2 more implementations I found, but lets stay on this one, how do I need to use it?

Comment: The Java class that you have posted has a main method. The main method shows you how to use it.

Comment: And keep in mind: To decode a FSK Signal you don't need FFT.

Comment: I tried to explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I understood your question now. You want to know how to decode a FSK Signal with android? And to do this you want to use the FFT?
You can achieve this without the FFT.

**Android Demo App**

[There is the source code](https://github.com/hitesh24by365/AudioJackTransfer) of an Android App that implements FSK Modulation/Demodulation.

The [FSKModule.java](https://github.com/hitesh24by365/AudioJackTransfer/blob/master/src/com/slk/androidaudio/fsk/FSKModule.java) implements a decoder that uses 3150Hz/1575Hz as mark/space. The important methods are `findStartBit`, `parseBits`, `processSound` and `countPeaks`. The implementation simply counts the number of peaks within a time slice. With the number of peaks you can infer to the corresponding frequency and decode the signal. This is easier and faster than using FFT.

**Why not using FFT?**

[There is a nice blog](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html) that describes [when to (not) use the FFT.](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/when-to-not-use-fft.html) (e.g. [Why EQ Is Done In the Time Domain](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/why-eq-is-done-in-time-domain.html) and [other interesting things](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html))