# How to record high quality audio from USB microphone without external libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, usb, android-usb

I am struggling on how to capture the audio stream from connected USB microphone. I have tried to use the `MediaCapture` with `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` as source which worked but recording quality isn't quite usable for me and you can't be sure if the audio source is really USB or the built in device microphone. What I need is to use the USB audio feature but so far I am unable to make any progress.

To use third-party libraries is overkill for me since I need to only receive the stream of audio data from the microphone, the rest of the processing is already done and working, only the audio source is the issue.

### What I need to do is:

1. Check if there is USB microphone connected to the device.
2. Find out what characteristics this device has (supported sampling rates, channels etc.)
3. Record audio data

### What I've done so far:

Generate a list of connected USB device which class is `UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO`

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = PACKAGE_NAME  + ".USB_PERMISSION";
private UsbManager mUsbManAndroid;
private Map<String, UsbDevice> mAndroidDeviceMap;
private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;

private ArrayList<UsbDeviceListItem> getUSBDevicesList() {
    // Enumerate USB devices
    mAndroidDeviceMap = mUsbManAndroid.getDeviceList();
    ArrayList<UsbDeviceListItem> usbDevicesList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String key : mAndroidDeviceMap.keySet()) {
        UsbDevice device = mAndroidDeviceMap.get(key);

        // Check the device class
        if (device.getDeviceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO) {
            usbDevicesList.add(usbDeviceToListItem(key, device));
        } else if (device.getDeviceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE) {
            UsbInterface interface;
            for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
                // Check if at least one interface is audio
                interface = device.getInterface(i);

                if (interface != null && interface.getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO) {
                    usbDevicesList.add(usbDeviceToSysBusUsbDevice(key, device));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here goes some code to identify the device using
    // linux shell commands if device SDK version is older 
    // than 21 (Lollipop). In older versions of Android
    // we can't get device's Vendor and Device names using
    // Android API, we need to use some linux shell commands.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    return usbDevicesList;
}
```

Request permission for selected usb device from the list:

```
 mUsbDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         UsbDeviceListItem usbDeviceItem = (UsbDeviceListItem) mUsbDeviceList.getItemAtPosition(i);
         UsbDevice device = mAndroidDeviceMap.get(usbDeviceItem.getDevicePath());

         manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
     }
 });
```

Permission broadcast receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(device != null){
                        streamFromUsbDevice(device)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(SensorActivity.this, "Permission denied for device " + device,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Sample method for reading data from the USB device

```
private void streamFromUSBDevice(UsbDevice device) {
    UsbEndpoint endpoint;
    UsbInterface usbInterface;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here was code for finding the first audio interface with its
    // endpoint. But because I failed to make it work I was manually
    // getting them by index.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    usbInterface = device.getInterface(2);
    endpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0);

    if (endpoint == null)  {
        Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.endpoint_not_found));
        notifyUser(R.string.endpoint_not_found);
        return;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, R.string.connecting_to_usb_device);
    notifyUser(R.string.connecting_to_usb_device);

    UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
    connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true);

    while (true) {
        if (!isRecording) {
            // Close the connection to the usb device
            connection.close();

            notifyUser(R.string.status_idle);                
            break;
        }

        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        request.initialize(connection, endpoint);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[endpoint.getMaxPacketSize()];

        final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);

        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting queue...");
        if (!request.queue(buf, buffer.length)) {
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.error_queue_request)));
            notifyUser(R.string.error_queue_request);
            isRecording = false;
            break;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting response...");
        final UsbRequest response = connection.requestWait();

        if (response == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Null response!");
            notifyUser(R.string.null_response);
            isRecording = false;
            break;
        }


        final int nRead = buf.position();

        if (nRead > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Streaming " + nRead + " bytes to UI");
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putShortArray(ARG_RECORDED_DATA, byte2short(buffer));

            sendMessageToUI(SHOW_AUDIO_DATA_PACKET, args, null);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "No data in buffer!");
            notifyUser(R.string_empty_buffer);

            isRecording = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am getting from this is that `request.queue()` is always returning **false**.

I have also attempted to use the `connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, buffer, buffer.length, 0);` method but the result is always **-1**.

If someone was in similar situation please help.

P.S. The error I am receiving in the log is: `UsbRequestJNI: request is closed in native_queue`.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: After upgrading my project to API 25 and minSdkVersion to 21, I am using android native support for secondary audio source (MIC). This saved me trouble integrating any third party native libraries.

Comment: I want to capture audio from any USB input. Will above code works in that condition?

Comment: No, the above code is on totally wrong path. You can use the MediaRecorder and select MIC as your source. Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499042/android-audiorecord-example/13487250#13487250

Comment: Ohh.. will try that approach. Thanks

Comment: Hi if you can share the working snippet would be of help