# Android AudioRecord read always returns -3 (ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION)

Tags: java, android, audiorecord

I have tried simplifying the code to the bare minimum and it still doesn't work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AudioRecord rec;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rec=  new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,8192);

    short buff[] = new short[8192];
    int read = rec.read(buff,0,buff.length);
    System.out.print(read);
}
```

Always returns -3 no matter what. What am I missing?

Comment: I'd still like some help on this please

Comment: OK so a friend told me to try and change the array size to half the buffer size. That makes it return 0 instead. Better than -3 for sure, but still does not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Together with my friend we have finally managed to solve this issue. You need to call AudioRecord.startRecording() before calling read(). Also after you're done you should call AudioRecord.stop(). I wonder why it's so hard to find this basic piece of information

Comment: vivo x6 android 4.2.1 still does not work, it shows:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.

Comment: this thread solved my vivo's problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing

Answer (score 3):

Did you checked the permissions in manifest ?

```
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

*Documentation says :*

Reads audio data from the audio hardware for recording into a byte array. The format specified in the AudioRecord constructor should be ENCODING_PCM_8BIT to correspond to the data in the array.

***Parameters***

audioData   byte: the array to which the recorded audio data is written.
This value must never be null.

offsetInBytes   int: index in audioData from which the data is written expressed in bytes.

sizeInBytes int: the number of requested bytes.
Returns

int zero or the positive number of bytes that were read, or one of the following error codes. The number of bytes will not exceed sizeInBytes.

**ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION if the object isn't properly initialized**

i think you should check the initialization of AudioRecord object. 
So look at this answer : [Android AudioRecord example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499042/android-audiorecord-example)

Comment: Ye added it right after </application> still nothing. Also tried adding ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},200); so now it asks for permission but to no effect

Comment: Can you paste the exception here please ?

Comment: There is no exception, it just returns -3 which is the error code for ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION

Comment: I think you read the wrong docs, the one you read is for byte and I an using the short version which should be used with 16 bit encoding. Also the array is initialized properly

Answer (score 2):

According to the Android documentation -

-3 indicates that it is an [invalid operation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION).

> Denotes a failure due to the improper use of a method.
>
> Constant Value: -3 (0xfffffffd)

This problem is mostly likely because it couldn't create an `AudioRecord` instance with the parameters that you have specified.

After you create the object try to check whether it was initialized correctly via the method `getState`

```
    if (rec.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
        // Oops looks like it was not initalized correctly
    }
```

If it is the state is indeed uninitialized then try setting different audio properties. Check the documentation for `AudioRecord` [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#AudioRecord(int, int, int, int, int)), the documentation provides a comprehensive details on how to initialize the different parameters.