# Android capture internal (application) audio

Tags: android, audio

I want to capture internal audio, programmatically. For instance, I want to play an audio file (on my device) and then capture the audio output - not using the microphone with the volume turned up.

Example use case: I want to make a library that other developers can use in their games, allowing users to record in-game audio.

Android says there is [Playback Capture functionality](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture#building_a_capture_app), however, I just cannot find an example. I've googled for hours. Whenever I google 'android capture app sounds' or 'android record audio', I either get links to voice recording apps or some code recording from the microphone (usually nearly 10 years old)... [e.g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499042/android-audiorecord-example)

Does anyone have a link to a working example?

Answer (score -1):

You can reference `MediareCorder` with https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder

Comment: Sorry, but what does that mean?